# Tag request: [tag:analytic-form]

Tags: feature-request, tags

This question:

[Steps to figure out a posterior distribution when it might be simple enough to have an analytic form?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/steps-to-figure-out-a-posterior-distribution-when-it-might-be-simple-enough-to-h)

leads me to idea we need [analytic-form](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-form) tag. There might be plenty other similar questions asking on the analytic form of some bayesian posterior. I'd be interested in this group of questions; and I think they should be tagged somehow.

Comment: I'm sure the moderators would be more than happy to add this tag, but they'd need a few examples of questions that would be improved by having this tag added to them!